# Print all pages in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to print all pages of kendo grid
I search alot I used this link 
http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/controls/data-management/grid/walkthrough#printing

to print grid ,but it print the current page.
like this 
[image]

note linked name still appear as linked and user can press it in print page.

I tried to use this code to load all pages , but it is not work since it show print page then load grid with all page items

```
 var dataSource = gridElement.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    dataSource.pageSize(dataSource.total());
```

I want to print all pages of grid in friendly layout , like one export grid to pdf it export friendly grid to print

**Edit 1**

here is my script to print all grid pages but it not work

```
$('#printGrid').click(function () {
    printGrid();
});
function printGrid() {
    var gridElement = $('#PageGrid'),
        printableContent = '',
        win = window.open('', '', 'width=800, height=500');
    var dataSource = gridElement.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    dataSource.pageSize(dataSource.total());

    var htmlStart =
       '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
       '<html>' +
       '<head>' +
       '<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/' + kendo.version + '/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> ' +
       '<meta charset="utf-8" />' +
       '<title>@GlobalResources.Print</title>' +
       '<style>' +
       'html { font: 11pt sans-serif; }' +
       '.k-grid { border-top-width: 0; }' +
       '.k-grid, .k-grid-content { height: auto !important; }' +
       '.k-grid-content { overflow: visible !important; }' +
       'div.k-grid table { table-layout: auto; width: 100% !important; }' +
       '.k-grid .k-grid-header th { border-top: 1px solid; }' +
       '.k-grid-toolbar, .k-grid-pager > .k-link { display: none; }' +
       '</style>' +
       '</head>' +
       '<body>';

    var htmlEnd =
            '</body>' +
            '</html>';

    var gridHeader = gridElement.children('.k-grid-header');
    if (gridHeader[0]) {
        var thead = gridHeader.find('thead').clone().addClass('k-grid-header');
        printableContent = gridElement
            .clone()
                .children('.k-grid-header').remove()
            .end()
                .children('.k-grid-content')
                    .find('table')
                        .first()
                            .children('tbody').before(thead)
                        .end()
                    .end()
                .end()
            .end()[0].outerHTML;
    } else {
        printableContent = gridElement.clone()[0].outerHTML;
    }

    doc = win.document.open();
    doc.write(htmlStart + printableContent + htmlEnd);
    doc.close();
    win.print();

}
```

Comment: update and put my code

Comment: did you get any solution to your problem? Please share how did you deal with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var gridElement = $('#PopUpGrid'),
             printableContent = '',
             win = window.open('', '', 'width=800, height=500, resizable=1, scrollbars=1'),
             doc = win.document.open();

         var htmlStart =
             '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
             '<html>' +
             '<head>' +
             '<meta charset="utf-8" />' +
             '<title>Kendo UI Grid</title>' +
             '<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/' + kendo.version + '/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> ' +
             '</head>' +
             '<body>';

         var htmlEnd =
             '</body>' +
             '</html>';

         var gridHeader = gridElement.children('.k-grid-header');
         if (gridHeader[0]) {
             var thead = gridHeader.find('thead').clone().addClass('k-grid-header');
             printableContent = gridElement
                 .clone()
                 .children('.k-grid-header').remove()
                 .end()
                 .children('.k-grid-content')
                 .find('table')
                 .first()
                 .children('tbody').before(thead)
                 .end()
                 .end()
                 .end()
                 .end()[0].innerHTML;
         } else {
             printableContent = gridElement.clone()[0].innerHTML;
         }

         doc.write(htmlStart + printableContent + htmlEnd);
         doc.close();
         win.print();
     }
```

I hope you find it usefull. feel free to comment my errors
thanks.

Comment: How does this answer different from single-page print solution mentioned in https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/export/print-export ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is that you are are setting

`var dataSource = gridElement.data("kendoGrid").dataSource; dataSource.pageSize(dataSource.total());`

inside your printGrid(). When you call dataSource.pageSize() then grid needs some time to reload records as per new pagesize and therefore your printGrid code doesn't wait for grid dataBound event to get completed. Hence you will only see the current page in your print preview as the grid reload is not completed yet.

So in order to solve this problem. First set datasource page size when user click print button like below:

```
$('#printGrid').click(function () {
          var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
          dataSource.pageSize(dataSource.total());
           
        });
```

Then You need to move the method call printGrid() method to grid's dataBound event with the condition when pagesize equals the total record as below. This condition will confirm that the user has clicked on the print button. As earlier we had set data source pagesize to total record count in printGrid() method:

```
dataBound: function(e){
               var grid = this;
               if(grid.dataSource.data().length === grid.dataSource.total())
              {
                printGrid();
               }
          },
```

With this change now printGrid() only get call once grid reload is completed. I have prepared a full working example at dojo :
https://dojo.telerik.com/@vishwas.upadhyay@neuralt.com/uBAMOpuq

**Cons**
Loading all the records for printing has a serious problems when record size is larger. The browser will take a significant amount of time to load thousands of records or it might be unresponsive. So if your application renders a large number of records then you should be extra careful with this approach.